# how to make conditional block in regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to match every line where if the line has "event4" then also must have "event70" or "event71", if it doesnt have "event4", match it also. Using Regular expresions.

Input:

```
event4,event56,event70
event5, event72
No event number
event4,event56
```

Rows expected to be matched:

```
event4,event56,event70
event5, event72
No event number
```

Regex:

```
preg_match( "/(?:event4,(.*(event70|event71)+)|.*)/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Now is matching all of the rows.

Comment: `explode()` on comma, then `in_array()`

Comment: You need to use a negative lookaround in the `.*` alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way using `(*SKIP)`:

```
/^(?:event4\b(*SKIP).*event7[01])?.*$/m
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/gA8nQ2/4)

I assume that events are sorted (event4 is always before event70).
If `event4` is not always at the begining of the line, you can add `.*?` at the start of the pattern (after the anchor).

**How does it work:**

`(*SKIP)` forces the regex engine to not retry the characters matched on the left when the subpattern on the right (`.*event7[01]`) fails. Consequence, if event70 or event71 are not found the next tries would begin after "event4," *(and would fail until the newline is reached because of the `^` anchor)*

Comment: @AdanZweig: remove the comma or replace it with `\b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?(event4)(?(event7(0|1)).+)|.*)/', $text, $matches);
```